# How to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^\frac{n^2+n}{2}}{\Pi_{i=1}^n (2^i-1)} < \infty$?

Tags: calculus, limits, infinite-product

The problem is as follows:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^\frac{n^2+n}{2}}{\Pi_{i=1}^n (2^i-1)}$$

I'm stuck on where to go with this. When I plug the problem into Wolfram Alpha, I get [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Limit%5B2%5E%28%28n%5E2%2Bn%29%2F2%29%2FProduct%5B%282%5Ei-1%29%2C%7Bi%2C1%2Cn%7D%5D%2Cn-%3E%E2%88%9E%5D), which I can't decipher, as I'm not familiar with the q-Pochhammer Symbol or its properties.

The only thing I've been able to try is factoring out a $2^n$ from the top and bottom, but this still leaves me stuck on where to go. Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you pay attention to the Wolfram Alpha result you'll notice that it wasn't able to interpret your input correctly, so the answer is unrelated to your question.

Comment: @jjagmath I see that now. How could I query it correctly? Putting parenthesis around the expression doesn't work.

Comment: @jjagmath Got it: [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Limit%5B2%5E%28%28n%5E2%2Bn%29%2F2%29%2FProduct%5B%282%5Ei-1%29%2C%7Bi%2C1%2Cn%7D%5D%2Cn-%3E%E2%88%9E%5D).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to prove it converges (numerically, to some number $\ell \approx 3.46274662$), you can do as follows: since
$$
\frac{2^\frac{n^2+n}{2}}{\prod_{i=1}^n (2^i-1)} = \frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{2^i}\right)}
$$
is is sufficient to show that $a_n := \prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{2^i}\right)$ converges to some positive number; equivalently, that $b_n := \log a_n$ converges to some real number. Now,
$$
\log a_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \log \left(1-\frac{1}{2^i}\right)
$$
and this converges by comparison with $-\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2^i}$.

Answer (score 3):

We have
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^\frac{n^2+n}{2}}{\prod_{i=1}^n (2^i-1)} &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^\frac{n^2+n}{2}}{\prod_{i=1}^n (2^i(1-2^{-i}))}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^\frac{n^2+n}{2}}{(\prod_{i=1}^n 2^i)(\prod_{i=1}^n(1-2^{-i}))}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^\frac{n^2+n}{2}}{2^{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i}\prod_{i=1}^n(1-2^{-i})}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^\frac{n^2+n}{2}}{2^{\frac{n^2+n}{2}}\prod_{i=1}^n(1-2^{-i})}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^n(1-2^{-i})}\\
&= \frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^\infty(1-2^{-i})} = \frac{1}{\phi(\tfrac{1}{2})}\\
\end{align}

where $\phi$ is the [Euler q-series function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function) and since there's no closed form is known for this function, your question can't be further simplified.